# How to Prevent a Background Image Covering Border Image

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a ragged boarder to a parchment background. This is my CSS

```
#wrap
{
    width:52em;
    margin:30px auto; /* centers the container */
    background-image: url(../images/parchment.gif);
}
.borderimage #wrap
{
    border-width: 10px;
    -chrome-border-image: url(../images/parchment_border.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
    -moz-border-image: url(../images/parchment_border.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(../images/parchment_border.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(../images/parchment_border.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
    border-image: url(../images/parchment_border.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;
}
```

The .borderimage class is part of modernizr.

When it's rendered, the background image covers the boarder image. If I set the background image to none, I see the boarder image at the borders. I had this working a couple of years ago, but it failed some time ago. I don't if it was because of a change I made or browser upgrades. A web search didn't turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `background-size: contain;` within `#wrap`

Comment: are you repeating the background as well?

Comment: I don't specify repeat, but it must as the wrap division can be quite long. I originally had the modernizr css set the background image to none. I think that used to work because the border image filled the center and the background image wasn't needed. Now the border image is only shown in the border.